# Unrar and Progress Bar Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract a RAR file in a destination directory with the unrar command, but I don't want to display the normal file list that unrar shows when executing. What I want to do instead, is show a progress bar that shows the process in percentages using a `dialog --gauge`, but so far I only get the error

> syntax error: unexpected end of file

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest="testing"
file"example.rar"
cmd="$(unrar x "$file" "$dest")" &>/dev/null

fc="$(unrar l "$file" | wc -l)" # get file count inside RAR file
fc="$((fc-10))" # file count has 10 extra lines, remove them
i=0  # index counter
(
  for f in "$cmd"; do
    pct="$(( 100*(++i)/fc ))"  # calculate percentage
    cat <<EOF
    XXX
    $pct
    Extracting file "$f"...
    XXX
    EOF
  done
) | dialog --title "Extracting Files" --gauge "Please wait" 7 70 0
```

So far, the code extracts the files in the `dest` folder, but they don't show the dialog box, and show the error `unexpected end of file` after completing the file extraction. It doesn't show any files being extracted which is to be expected by using `&>/dev/null` but I cannot get the dialog box to display properly.

I got this code from various examples I found online, but so far I cannot make it work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Well, since no one has answered my question, I'm gonna answer it myself. I Finally managed to make the program work, it extracts the files, prints the pathnames of the files being extracted, and display the gauge bar filling correctly as each file is extracted. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest="testing" # destination directory
file"example.rar"

(
fc="$(unrar l "$file" | wc -l)" # get file count inside RAR file
fc="$((fc-10))" # file count has 10 extra lines, remove them
i=0  # index counter
unrar x "$file" "$dest" | while IFS="" read -r in ; do
  # extract the pathname of file being extracted
  f=$(echo $in | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

  echo "XXX"
  echo "$f..." # Display file name in the dialog box
  echo "XXX"
  echo "$pct %" # Show percent
  pct="$(( 100*(++i)/fc ))" # Calculate current percent
done
) | dialog --title "Extracting Files" --gauge "Please wait" 8 75 0
```

This next part is supposed to capture the result of executing the extraction of the .RAR file, however I'm unsure if at this point I'm just capturing the result of the execution of the dialog box or that of the unrar command. What I want to do is control the flow the script in case the unrar command fails, I'm not entirely sure of how I should proceed, but right now, after the line where I display the dialog, I put the following if-then:

```
if [ "$?" ]; then
  clear
  echo "Command successful"
fi
```

Is this correct or should I move the if-then block to somewhere else in the code?

In the meantime, Imma work in a way to make this script work like a kind of prettied up unrar command, where you can specify the file name to be extracted and an optional destination directory, that way I'll be able to eliminate the need to specify a destination directory

Edit:

This is the current code I'm using for the solution of my own question. So far the code seems to be handling errors just fine. I have tested it only with the "File already exist" kind of errors that halts the execution of the script to wait for input from the user, and CRC errors for the cases where you have partitioned the compressed files in various parts and one of them is missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
dest="testing" # destination directory
file="example.rar"

(
  fc="$(unrar l "$file" | wc -l)" # get file count inside RAR file
  fc="$((fc-10))" # file count has 10 extra lines, remove them
  i=0  # index counter

  # I have to redirect the output from 0 to 1 because when there's a
  # "file already exists" kind of error, unrar halts the execution of the
  # script to wait for user input, so I have to process that message inside
  # of the loop
  unrar x "$file" "$dest" 0>&1 2>&1 | while IFS="" read -r in ; do

    # we got a "file already exists" message?
    if [[ "$f" == *"already"* ]]; then
      echo "Error"  # display an error message
      break         # exit the while loop
    fi

    # extract the pathname of file being extracted
    f=$(echo $in | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

    echo "XXX"
    echo "$f..." # Display file name in the dialog box
    echo "XXX"
    echo "$pct %" # Show percent
    pct="$(( 100*(++i)/fc ))" # Calculate current percent
  done

  exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} # exit with status message we got from unrar

) | dialog --title "Extracting Files" --gauge "Please wait" 8 75 0

# if PIPESTATUS[0] is not equal to zero, it means there was an error
if [[ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "There was an error." # display a message
  exit 1  # exit with status 1
fi

# if command was successful, display a message  
if (( "$?" == 0 )); then
  echo "Command executed correctly $?"
fi
```

So far, I'm not doing anything with the errors, I'm just interested in detecting them and returning messages to the scripts that call this one. It seems to be working just fine, but I know there has to be a better way to do this. What are your thoughts?

Comment: `if [ "$?" ]` is always true. It's exactly equivalent to `[ -n "$?" ]`, which asks if `$?` expands to an empty string. Whether 0, 1, or anything else, it's always non-empty.

Comment: `if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]` is perhaps what you were aiming to write, or the bash-y equivalent `if (( $? == 0 ))`, though using `$?` at all is a bit of a code smell; better to directly put the command being tested inside an `if` statement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm trying to test the result of the unrar execution to catch errors (as you might already know), but since the command is being executed inside a sub shell (as far as my understanding goes) and then the result of the subshell is being redirected to the dialog (which is what I think is happening here), catching errors inside the subshell won't affect the execution of the dialog? My intention is to stop the execution of the command as soon as an error happens. What would be the best solution to catch errors in this code?

Comment: Put a `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` directly after the `done` inside the subshell, and then you can refer to `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` *outside* the subshell to refer to the first element of that pipeline (being the subshell itself). Or you could `set -o pipefail`.

Comment: That said, I'd avoid setting your pipes up this way at all. Better to use process substitution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd upvote your comments but I can't and I don't know why...Anyways, I noticed that when the files already exists in the destination directory, the program hangs, I'm trying to look for a way around this since the unrar results are being redirected to the while, so I guess I'd have to catch the error inside the while. So far I've have no idea how to do it...I think I'd have to try again tomorrow :D thanks anyway for your suggestions, I'll be sure to check them out.

Comment: I'd suggest redirecting stdin from `/dev/null` to ensure that there's no blocking on input.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I managed to do it like this: unrar x "$file" "$dest" 0>&1 2>&1 and then left everything else the way it is. Oh....and added an if inside the while to check for the message "already" that's returned from the unrar command when the file already exists in the destination directory. When I encounter that message I break from the while and then I catch the result of ${PIPESTATUS[0]} like you suggested, so far it seems to be working fine. But I'll take a break from this code atm, I've been working all day in this and need a break :D It's a big script, this is just a part of it.

Comment: I'd... tend to suggest avoiding that approach. Pointing stdin to what is, in this context, the write-only side of a FIFO pair isn't exactly relying on well-defined behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean in your last comment.

Comment: Roughly: `0>&1`, when FD 1 is the writable end of a FIFO pair, is a bad idea.

Comment: Pipes are implemented with FIFOs; FIFOs have one read side and one write side, and attempts to read from the write side or write from the read side fail.

Comment: ...so, when you use `0>&1`, you're *assuming* that the software being run handles those failures gracefully. That's a big, and I'd argue unwarranted, assumption.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well...While I was trying out the unrar thing, I found out that when I try to extract the files to a directory where the files already exists, it breaks everything up. I need a script to run without intervention, and those kind of things, even if they're no errors perse, can wreak everything that's dependant on those files being extracted...anyways. If I redirect 0>&1 I can at least check for when the message is file already exists and at least halt the execution without mayor damage. But, if I redirect 0 to null, I won't be able to control the execution. How should I do it then?

Comment: Waitaminute. Are you assuming a TTY here? If so, make it explicit: `0</dev/tty`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well...when I do unrar x "$file" "$dest" 2>&1 0</dev/tty piped to while read, the program stops it's execution once it gets to the message from the unrar command asking for my input. And it only shows the error message outside of the subshell when I press ctrl-C. But, if I do it like unrar x "$file" "$dest" 0>&1 2>&1 piped to while read it works fine because I can detect the message inside the while. You said they way I'm doing it right now is not recommended, but the way you suggest is not working like I want to. What is the correct way?

Comment: Depends on what you actually want, which it seems I'm unclear on.

Comment: ...if you updated your answer to show current code including the error-handling case, that might help.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's my intention, I mean, posting the whole thing in here, I've not finished working on this script because I moved on to working in other things, I'm trying to automate a big process, but I intend to retake finishing this one up. I'm working in the parts that work with the extracted files, but I'm working in C++ right now. I'll make sure to post my answer as soon as possible. Thanks for your help anyways, I just didn't want to get stuck in a part I can't make to work in the way I want it to, so I kept going...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hello there, I uptaded my answer to show the current working code. Let me know what you think.